# Is there any way to print any extended information on StackOverflowException?

Tags: c#, exception, stack-overflow

One of my clients reported that the software I develop terminates unexpectedly. In app log, the only text available is `Process is terminated due to StackOverflowException.` There is no more information which would help me diagnose and fix it.

Is there any way to get the location where the exception was thrown? VS breaks on StackOverflowException, but is there any feasible method of diagnosing it without running the application in the debugger (or looking for it in all methods which contain recursion)?

Comment: I found some URL which can help http://www.forbeslindesay.co.uk/post/47974551480/a-tip-for-debugging-stack-overflow-exceptions-in of course if you can debug it

Comment: Add a decent logging system to your solution, (think along the lines of log4net), and make sure you log the stack trace and inner exception when a crash occurs.

Comment: @TimothyGroote Please post answers as answers, not comments. But if you did post that as an answer, it should be downvoted as it's wrong. That just plain doesn't and cannot work for stack overflows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot normally execute any code after a stack overflow, it's one of the rare uncatchable fatal exceptions, so you cannot simply catch it to log any extended details.

The only way you could work around that is by tracking the exceptions from outside of the code that has a stack overflow. You would need to create a native code application to hosts the CLR. If you do that, you can specify that `StackOverflowException` is not 100% fatal. This is briefly mentioned on the [`StackOverflowException` MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stackoverflowexception.aspx):

> If your app hosts the common language runtime (CLR), it can specify that the CLR should unload the application domain where the stack overflow exception occurs and let the corresponding process continue. For more information, see [ICLRPolicyManager Interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164394.aspx).

But even that would still mean that a simple `try`...`catch` is not sufficient to actually catch the exception. You would have to make sure that the exception handling is not done from the app domain that has a stack overflow. It might be done from a different app domain, or it might be done from unmanaged code.

Comment: Does a StackOverflow only crash the specific AppDomain in which it occurs or does the whole CLR go down?

Comment: @Asad Isn't that already answered by the quote in my answer? It says that normally the whole process can no longer continue, but if you host the runtime yourself, you can change it so only the specific app domain gets killed.

Comment: Ah yes, sorry. Didn't understand the quote first time I read it.